# Why does not read the whole text file?

Tags: c#, image, file, tga

In C#, I would like to read a .tga picture into a string variable. 
I use many of variations to read from a text file, but there is a problem with every solution.
The file size 17Kb
Why doesn't read the whole text?

For example this does not work:

```
string item = "";
while ((item = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   picture_string += sr.ReadLine()+"";                      
}
```

It does not work:

```
picture_string = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

It does not work

```
picture_string = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Comment: _Doesn't work_ doesn't helpful. You get any exception or error message? Did you debug your code as well? What is `sr`? What is `path`?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? And why you are mixing reading from text files and reading of picture files in your question?

Comment: A ".tga" file is NOT a text file. You can't read it as a text file.

Comment: It does not read the whole text files only the peace of it. For example the text file contains 18162 chars and it reads only 16866.

Comment: I don't get any error message, the program works correctly, but it does not read the whole(!) text.

Comment: You are reading a binary file as if it were a text file. There are no lines in binary files yet by calling `ReadLine` not only do you omit the bytes with values equivalent to newline, you also convert them to irrelevant character representations.

Comment: Try `File.ReadAllBytes(path)`. Stop trying to read a binary file as if it is a text file.

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes(path);
This is the solution!!!!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you are trying to read is a *binary* file, not a *text* file. Stop trying to read a binary file as if it is a text file.

```
var fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```